# Spring, I have no application-context for testing. What is wrong with that?

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc

I am 1 day old to Spring

This is how my test looks

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration
public class PropertyReaderTest {

    @Autowired
    private PropertyReader propertyReader;
    @Test
    public void testGetProfile() throws Exception {
        System.out.printf(System.getProperty("spring.active.profiles"));
        assertEquals("development", propertyReader.getProfile());
    }
}
```

This is my source class

```
@Component
public class PropertyReader {
    @Value("${spring.active.profiles")
    private String profile;

    @Nonnull
    public String getProfile() {
        return profile;
    }
```

and maven dependency

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

My tests fail

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_55.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java -ea -Dspring.active.profiles=development -Didea.launcher.port=7536 "-Didea.launcher.bin.path=/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA 13.app/bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA 13.app/lib/idea_rt.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA 13.app/plugins/junit/lib/junit-rt.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_55.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/ant-javafx.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_55.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/dt.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_55.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/javafx-doclet.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_55.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/javafx-mx.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_55.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/jconsole.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_55.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/sa-jdi.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_55.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/tools.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_55.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/charsets.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_55.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/deploy.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_55.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/htmlconverter.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_55.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/javaws.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_55.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jce.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_55.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jfr.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_55.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jfxrt.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_55.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jsse.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_55.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/management-agent.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_55.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/plugin.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_55.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/resources.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_55.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/rt.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_55.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/dnsns.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_55.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/localedata.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_55.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/sunec.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_55.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/sunjce_provider.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_55.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/sunpkcs11.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_55.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/zipfs.jar:/Users/harith/IdeaProjects/pryme_services/external_services/ifs/target/test-classes:/Users/harith/IdeaProjects/pryme_services/external_services/ifs/target/classes:/Users/harith/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/jersey/core/jersey-client/2.7/jersey-client-2.7.jar:/Users/harith/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/jersey/core/jersey-common/2.7/jersey-common-2.7.jar:/Users/harith/.m2/repository/javax/ws/rs/javax.ws.rs-api/2.0/javax.ws.rs-api-2.0.jar:/Users/harith/.m2/repository/javax/annotation/javax.annotation-api/1.2/javax.annotation-api-1.2.jar:/Users/harith/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/jersey/bundles/repackaged/jersey-guava/2.7/jersey-guava-2.7.jar:/Users/harith/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/hk2/hk2-api/2.2.0/hk2-api-2.2.0.jar:/Users/harith/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/hk2/hk2-utils/2.2.0/hk2-utils-2.2.0.jar:/Users/harith/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/hk2/external/aopalliance-repackaged/2.2.0/aopalliance-repackaged-2.2.0.jar:/Users/harith/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/hk2/external/javax.inject/2.2.0/javax.inject-2.2.0.jar:/Users/harith/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/hk2/hk2-locator/2.2.0/hk2-locator-2.2.0.jar:/Users/harith/.m2/repository/org/javassist/javassist/3.18.1-GA/javassist-3.18.1-GA.jar:/Users/harith/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/hk2/osgi-resource-locator/1.0.1/osgi-resource-locator-1.0.1.jar:/Users/harith/.m2/repository/com/google/code/findbugs/jsr305/2.0.1/jsr305-2.0.1.jar:/Users/harith/.m2/repository/junit/junit/4.8.1/junit-4.8.1.jar:/Users/harith/.m2/repository/yahoo/yinst/jports_org_springframework__spring_test/org_springframework__spring_test/3.0.5_1/org_springframework__spring_test-3.0.5_1.jar:/Users/harith/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-context/4.0.3.RELEASE/spring-context-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:/Users/harith/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-aop/4.0.3.RELEASE/spring-aop-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:/Users/harith/.m2/repository/aopalliance/aopalliance/1.0/aopalliance-1.0.jar:/Users/harith/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-beans/4.0.3.RELEASE/spring-beans-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:/Users/harith/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-core/4.0.3.RELEASE/spring-core-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:/Users/harith/.m2/repository/commons-logging/commons-logging/1.1.3/commons-logging-1.1.3.jar:/Users/harith/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-expression/4.0.3.RELEASE/spring-expression-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar" com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter -ideVersion5 com.yahoo.pryme_services.external_services.ifs.PropertyReaderTest,testGetProfile
May 01, 2014 12:44:38 PM org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager retrieveTestExecutionListeners
INFO: @TestExecutionListeners is not present for class [class com.yahoo.pryme_services.external_services.ifs.PropertyReaderTest]: using defaults.
May 01, 2014 12:44:38 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [com/yahoo/pryme_services/external_services/ifs/PropertyReaderTest-context.xml]
May 01, 2014 12:44:38 PM org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager prepareTestInstance
SEVERE: Caught exception while allowing TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener@3b1aed57] to prepare test instance [com.yahoo.pryme_services.external_services.ifs.PropertyReaderTest@64d40911]
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.getApplicationContext(TestContext.java:308)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:109)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:75)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:321)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:220)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:301)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:303)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:240)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:180)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:157)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:74)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:211)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:67)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:134)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from class path resource [com/yahoo/pryme_services/external_services/ifs/PropertyReaderTest-context.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [com/yahoo/pryme_services/external_services/ifs/PropertyReaderTest-context.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:343)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:180)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:216)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:187)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:251)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:81)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:1)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.loadApplicationContext(TestContext.java:280)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.getApplicationContext(TestContext.java:304)
    ... 27 more
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [com/yahoo/pryme_services/external_services/ifs/PropertyReaderTest-context.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getInputStream(ClassPathResource.java:158)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:329)
    ... 36 more


java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.getApplicationContext(TestContext.java:308)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:109)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:75)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:321)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:220)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:301)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:303)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:240)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:180)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:157)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:74)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:211)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:67)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:134)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from class path resource [com/yahoo/pryme_services/external_services/ifs/PropertyReaderTest-context.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [com/yahoo/pryme_services/external_services/ifs/PropertyReaderTest-context.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:343)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:180)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:216)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:187)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:251)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:81)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:1)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.loadApplicationContext(TestContext.java:280)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.getApplicationContext(TestContext.java:304)
    ... 27 more
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [com/yahoo/pryme_services/external_services/ifs/PropertyReaderTest-context.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getInputStream(ClassPathResource.java:158)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:329)
    ... 36 more


Process finished with exit code 255
```

I looked at [docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/reference/html/testing.html) and they have code like

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "/simple-job-launcher-context.xml", 
                                    "/jobs/skipSampleJob.xml" })
public class SkipSampleFunctionalTests extends AbstractJobTests { ... }
```

But I do not have any such context files, what am I missing?

Comment: You need to configure Spring [some way](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.9.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-factory-metadata). Either you need to create a context file or use bean-based configuration. I recommend talking to your coworkers to get an example, or go to the Spring website and download an example.

Comment: The last `Caused By` in your stack trace gives the hint: `java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [com/yahoo/pryme_services/external_services/ifs/PropertyReaderTest-context.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist`.  The file you are telling it to load isn't there, or at least the app code doesn't believe it's there.

Answer (score 8):

When you simply leave your ContextConfiguration empty, like so..

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration // nothing defined here
public class PropertyReaderTest {
```

... then it will look at default locations for a context definition.  This typically comes in a form of an xml file where you would define beans and 'context' information.

In that xml file, you'll want to make a bean definition of your PropertyReader that you are trying to have Spring @Autowire.  You didn't expect Spring to just know how to do it without some instructions did you? ;)  As much magic as Spring does, you'll need to help it define some things.

Perhaps you wanted to run a standalone JUnit test file that has everything defined in itself.  You could then define your class like this:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes=PropertyReaderTest.class)
public class PropertyReaderTest {
```

You're telling the JUnit to look in your own class for Context definitions and it will read whatever annotation definitions you've added in your JUnit class.

Just remember that when you want Spring to read things in "Context", the context needs to be defined... in some form or another.

If you don't want to explicitly define all your components, you can have Spring look for them.  But still, you need to create a context that tells Spring to do that.  See here: 
http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.0.M3/reference/html/ch04s12.html

Answer (score 1):

the context file in spring is required to configure and register the beans.

if we dont want to use it, we should configure the beans in some other way.

so we will use another solution for your problem(java based bean configuration)

```java
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(loader=AnnotationConfigContextLoader.class)
public class PropertyReaderTest {

@Configuration
    static class ContextConfiguration {

        // this bean will be injected into the OrderServiceTest class
        @Bean
        public PropertyReader getPropertyReader () {
            PropertyReader propertyReader  = new PropertyReader();
            // set profile property and other properties, etc.
            return propertyReader;
        }
    }

    @Autowired
    private PropertyReader propertyReader;

    @Test
    public void testGetProfile() throws Exception {
        System.out.printf(System.getProperty("spring.active.profiles"));
        assertEquals("development", propertyReader.getProfile());
    }
}
```